# SEO, joomla and 2 domains for 2 languages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I’ve been looking around for the answer but I can't seem to find it. This is what I need:

1. `www.domain1.it/en` -> `www.domain2.com/en`
2. `www.domain2.com/it` -> `www.domain1.it/it`

I have tried a lot of possible solutions but no one works

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/it/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain1.it/it [R=301,L]
```

It doesn’t work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/it/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.it/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It doesn’t work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/it/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.it/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It doesn’t work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/it/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.it/it/ [R=301,L]
```

It doesn’t work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/it/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.it/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn’t work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond $1 !^en/$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.it/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think some of your attempts would work, but your problem is probably your browser caching redirects making your debugging unreliable.

I think the following redirects are simpler and will do what you want.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^it(.*) http://www.domain1.it/it$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en(.*) http://www.domain2.com/en$1 [R=301,L]
```